# Runtime Compilation of DLL for COM Interop

Tags: c#, dll, office-interop, system-codedom-compiler

I am working on a project that builds mathematical models for a user and then can output them in different formats. Right now I support outputting in Python, Java, C++. This works, I just autogenerate the code and call it a day.

However, a new request has been made. The user wants to be able to use the models from within Excel. I did some searching and found http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/

So this is a nice start but I need to do this programmatically. The models are stored as objects in the bigger program. If the user selects to export as a DLL for Excel, I would take some boilerplate code and insert the methods I would want to use.

However, it seems like I need to register the code for COM Interop. My test code creates a DLL I can use it C# and access its methods. But trying to add a reference in Excel 2000 (I know, I know, corporate sucks) VBA doesn't work. It seems that no TLB file is created, so there is nothing for it to load.

If I take the generated code compile it as a standalone having checked the make COM Visible and register for com interop boxes, the TLB is generated but Excel VBA throws an automation error.

So the actual questions.

1) How can I create at runtime a DLL that is Com Visible and Reistered for COM Interop?

2) How do I get Excel to play nice with it.

Simple Example DLL Code Follows:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace VSN
{

  [ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
  public class VSNFunctions
  {
      public VSNFunctions()
      {
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Adds 2 variables together.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name=\"v1\">First Param</param>
      /// <param name=\"v2\">Second Param</param>
      /// <returns>Sum of v1 and v2</returns>
      public double Add2(double v1, double v2)
      {
          return v1 + v2;
      }
      public double Sub2(double v1, double v2)
      {
          return v1 - v2;
      }
      public double Mul2(double v1, double v2)
      {
          return v1 * v2;
      }
      public double div2(double v1, double v2)
      {
          return v1 / v2;
      }

      [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
      public static void RegisterFunction(Type t)
      {
          Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("CLSID\\{"+t.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + "}\\Programmable");
      }


      [ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute]
      public static void UnregisterFunction(Type t)
      {
          Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey("CLSID\\{"+t.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + "}\\Programmable");
      }
  }
}
```

Code To Build the DLL programmitcally Follows:

```
CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
String exeName = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}.dll", System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "VSNTest");
MessageBox.Show(exeName);
parameters.OutputAssembly = exeName;

parameters.CompilerOptions = "/optimize";

CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, DLLString);
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Expose Code to VBA in a Visual C# Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608604.aspx)

To enable VBA code to call code in a Visual C# project, modify the code so it is visible to COM, and then set the ReferenceAssemblyFromVbaProject property to True in the designer.